# How to add/remove Parameters of a model placed inside a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there any way to add and remove Parameters inside of a model which is placed inside a pipeline, lets have a mock of this situation

Pipeline

```
Pipe_nusvc=Pipeline([('clf',NuSVC(
nu=0.5, kernel='rbf'))])
```

And i want to add this Parameter of NuSVC into the pipeline

```
gamma='scale'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your pipeline as you did:

```
Pipe_nusvc = Pipeline([
    ('clf', NuSVC(nu=0.5, kernel='rbf'))
])
```

Now you can modify inline:

```
Pipe_nusvc['clf'].gamma = 'auto'  # 'scale' is already the default
```

```
>>> Pipe_nusvc['clf']
NuSVC(gamma='auto')
```

Comment: that works fine ! , can you also mention how to remove it ?

Comment: @Ctrl7. It depends on the default value of the parameter. Here `Pipe_nusvc['clf'].gamma = 'scale'`